# Need to create function that returns a boolean when asked, "Is this a prime number?"

Tags: python, function, boolean, primes

I am trying to create a function that will test whether a number is a prime number and then return True or False. I am an extreme beginner at Python, so please make your code as simple as possible. Here's what I tried so far (only returns True):

```
def isPrime(x):

    x = int(x)
    for i in range(2, x):
        if(x % i == 0):
            x == False
        else:
            x == True

    return x
                
print(isPrime(input("Enter a prime number.")))
```

Comment: It will return `False` if you enter `0`.  Your `==` aren't doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest form of your program would be along the lines:

```
def isPrime(x):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False

        return True

    return False

print(isPrime(int(input("Enter a number: "))))
```

But this is not as efficient as it could be.  To do better, we would treat 2 (and all even numbers) as a special case and only allow the divisor to cover the odd numbers from 3 to the square root of the number we're testing.  The more divisions we can avoid, the faster it goes.

Ultimately using a Sieve of Eratosthenes will beat this approach, even with optimizations.

Comment: What if the input is 2 or lower?

Comment: @Rfroes87, I did note that this was the simplest working form of the OP's orignal code which included the *feature* you noted.  But, yes this should be handled and I've updated it.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your update still doesn't properly handle the case of `x = 2`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I run it, I enter 2, it returns True -- what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, it's what I was missing - `range` doesn't include the endpoint.  I thought it was going to test `if 2 % 2 == 0`, but it didn't.  My apologies.  P.S. no need for the loop to go to `x-1`, it can stop at `int(sqrt(x))`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I covered the square root issue in my explanatory text.

Comment: Sorry I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

You almost made it, just need to change it like this:

```
def isPrime(x):
    x = int(x)
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return x >= 2
                
print(isPrime(input("Enter a prime number.")))
```

EDIT: As pointed by @MarkRansom, when the `i` variable reaches the square root of `x`, it is safe to assume that there are no more possible divisors for it:

```
from math import sqrt

def isPrime(x):
    x = int(x)
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(x)) + 1):
    ...
```

Comment: You'd let the code keep doing (expensive) divisions even after it *knows* the answer?

Comment: It's not necessary to loop all the way to `x`, you can stop at `int(sqrt(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

When you typed this, I believe you meant as follows below:

```
def isPrime(x):
    x = int(x)
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            x = False
        else:
            x = True
    return x

print(isPrime(input("Enter a prime number.")))

## Which runs as follows in python IDLE:

>>> def isPrime(x):
        x = int(x)
        for i in range(2, x):
            if (x % i) == 0:
                x = False
            else:
                x = True
        return x
>>> print(isPrime(input("Enter a prime number.")))
Enter a prime number.11
True
>>> print(isPrime(input("Enter a prime number.")))
Enter a prime number.100
False
```

I know when I started out, I made many typing errors.
By rereading my code and lots of practice, I slowly got better.

Here's a how I would write out your task.

```
def isPrime(h):
    h = int(h)
    test = None
    for x in range(2, h):
        if (h%x) == 0:
            test = False
            print(f"{test}, the number {h} is not a prime!")
            break
    else:
        test = True
        print(f"{test}ly, the number {h} is a prime!")

## Then I'll run the call to the function in python IDLE as:
>>> 
>>> isPrime(input("Enter a number.\n"))
Enter a number.
11
Truely, the number 11 is a prime!
>>> 
>>> isPrime(input("Enter a number.\n"))
Enter a number.
110
False, the number 110 is not a prime!
>>>
```

One of most important things, that really helped me was:

- reading others code (and the docs!!)
- then play with their code in IDLE
- repeat the above                             <--------(I still do this all the time!!)